# Is it possible to make a scrollable element that still shows the overflow?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

On my page I have an container which has a max width regardless of the page/monitor width that contains all content (headlines, texts, images, etc.). I want to add a vertical list of images where the user can scroll through. The scrollbar (and therefore the image list) should be inside the inner container. Is it possible to show the overflowing images on the left and right side while still having the scrollbar? I've tried various combinations of `overflow: scroll` and `overflow: visible` but I couldn't get it to work. Is this even possible?

[image: sketch of the problem]

Comment: It is possible, but you will need to use some javascript and not just pure CSS.

Comment: You can create a placeholder div with overflow which shows a horizontal scrollbar and using jQuery you can scroll the main container where all items live by getting scroll % from the placeholder div.

Comment: as the other two mentioned I do not know any way without some javascript code. Check this example for a possible approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37515616/8820118